# How to make a "dialog box like" intent with multiple checkboxes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-spinner

I have an app that makes enterviews question by question. And there is a question type that shows people options as possible answers, using spinners. But there are questions that are a list of names in which the people will answer the same thing for many names, so instead of making the same question for every name, I would prefer to ask the question once and show the list of names down with the checkboxes for each one. But how to do that?

What I am able to do now:

[image]

What I want to do:

[image]

Sometimes we need more than `Yes` or `No` as like `Good`, `Bad`, `Worse` or `Low`, `Medium`, `High`...

EDIT:

**Example:**

What do you think of these candidates:

Barack Obama - (o) Okay ( ) Medium ( ) Not good () I don't know him

Mitt Hooney  - ( ) Okay ( ) Medium (o) Not good () I don't know him

Arnold Sw.   - ( ) Okay (o) Medium ( ) Not good () I don't know him

Comment: You can create a custom spinner with radio buttons inside, just google it custom spinner

Answer (score 0):

if you want more,

You can Use RadioButtonList

Comment: There is no such thing as a default widget for an android intent :(

Answer (score 0):

you can 
use Radio button list in alertBox, by using alertbox you can manage all things easily

as like this

```
final CharSequence[] gender = {"Male","Female"};
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(uploadphoto.this);
alert.setTitle("Select Gender");
alert.setSingleChoiceItems(gender,-1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        if(gender[which]=="Male")
        {
            gen="1";
        }
        else if (gender[which]=="Female")
        {
            gen="2";
        }
    }
});
alert.show();
```

Comment: This is not what I am talking about. This will show one question at a time. I need something that would show this gender questions X times in the same screen if there where X people that I am talking about, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this.

[image]

For more details, go through the link below. You will get complete source code:
http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-radiogroup.html

So according to your requirement you can change the number or RadioButton.

I have done from my side to achieve your requirement.

[image]

You asked for Title on the header, this is the main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="No"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="50" >
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

For complete source code, go through my Android Blog:
http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-radiongroup-and.html

Comment: Could I put a different text in each of those lines and a title as the question title in this intent of your example?

Comment: Yes you can put question text in each line as well as a title.
You need to add Title in your main.xml before ListView.